# Provider hosted high trust add-in authentication with CNG key storage provider | Invalid provider type specified

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, certificate

I have the same problem as [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/12/22/invalid-provider-type-specified-error-when-accessing-x509certificate2-privatekey-on-cng-certificates/), so I get the error: "Invalid provider type specified".

However .NET 4.6 added support for CNG certificate handling so no need for additional libraries.

What changes I need to make to TokenHelper.cs in order to use certificate with 
Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider instead of Microsoft RSA Schannel Cryptographic Provider.

Comment: Why do you want to use it? Are there any benefits?

Comment: Customer has it and they have problems converting the certificate.

Comment: In the end, customer managed to convert the certificate and everybody was happy :)